Griffiths image methode surface charge density
As Griffiths says:
there is a charge $q$ at a perpendicular distance $z=d$ from an infinite conducting plate $z=0$.  We use the image method and place $−q$ on the other side of the plate and calculate the potential. OK.
Now for calculating the surface charge density on the plane, it uses the equation 2.49 which is:
$$ -\sigma/\epsilon =\partial{V}/\partial{z}\vert_{z=0} $$
My problem is that, this equation is only true for a closed conductor with $V=0$ inside!
But here there is no such condition!
Even worse, when I take the Laplacian $\nabla{V}^2$ of the potential on $z \geq 0$ to get the $$ -\sigma/\epsilon $$ as it's a general formula, it equals to 0!
Now I'm honestly confused 

The potential inside a conductor is always constant, as the charges inside of it can move freely. This is contained in section 2.5.1 of Griffiths. This constant value is 0 here, because the plane is assumed to be grounded.
Moreover, you don't need to take the Laplacian, but rather, as you wrote, the partial derivative of the field with respect to $z$ at $z=0$. Then, you will find the surface density desired.

Yes I know that, but here the situation is not a closed shaped conductor, it is just a plane, and as the plane is connected to the ground, we don't know anything about the otherside.  BTW thanks for the edits ✨️

The conductor does not need a closed shape for this property to be true.

And the fact it is infinite is only an approximation, you can consider its dimensions are much bigger than the distance from the charge to it.

So, if I have a little conductor sheet, it makes all the potential of its side without charge 0? And if so, Where is the proof of this phenomena? It's really contradictory to my intuition...

The potential is contained inside of the sheet, there is no such thing as "contained in the other side", it is 0 at $z=0$. And look, if the sheet is small, then the distance between the charge and the sheet needs to be $\textit{much}$ smaller, and the equations derived above are only true in the vicinity of the charge. The infinite conducting plane does not exist and is only an approximation.

Many thanks, although my friends and I don't fully agree, but thanks for the effort and time ✨️
